# Are there are any Java libraries to talk to a PS3 controller?

Tags: java, bluetooth, playstation3

I received a Mindstorms NXT set for Christmas.  The first thing I did was install lejos on it so I can program the thing in Java.  I built my first robot which basically drives until it gets close to something then swings its arm in a stabbing motion.

I thought, what better than create some libraries so I can control this thing with a PS3 controller. I am searching online, but don't see much that talks to a PS3 controller from Java.  Anyone know of anything?

Comment: Does the thing have bluetooth?

Comment: Both the Mindstorm and the PS3 controller have bluetooth. ;)

Comment: Damn, where do you live that christmas is three days earlier than in the rest of the world? :)

Comment: Its more amusing when you control it through iPhone/iPod, but why? the Mindstorm application have lots of complicated stuff to do already

Comment: If you have to ask why, you must not be an engineer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a pure java lib for the sixaxis, as opposed to the wiimote, but there is a C++ library that allows a computer to be controller wirelessly via the controller:

[link](http://www.davieslim.com/ps3/use-ps3-controller-in-windows-wireless-bluetooth/)

I figure you can make that java simply by adding a wrapping through JNI... Of course it might be more work if you're not working with a pc.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I can run C++ and Java on the Mindstorm at the same time.  But I might be able to use the C++ library as a reference if it comes down to me attempting to decode the streams myself.